# how to customize gnome-screensaver on xfce desktop

Tags: gnome, xfce, screen-lock

I'm running GalliumOS on a Chromebook with gnome-screensaver as my screen locker. I am hoping to customize the lock-screen background but am having difficulty figuring out how to change it. It currently displays a different background from both the splash screen and the desktop background. Oddly enough it is also different from the default background for a new user. The desktop environment is `xfce4` so the full `gnome-shell` doesn't seem available and normal configuration editing seems to not be working.

I started digging around for configuration files for `gnome-screensaver` but can't figure out where they are saved. The best I could find in the `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/xfce4/xfconf` directory was the `xfce4-desktop.xml` file. Which set the `image-path` property of the `xfce-desktop` channel to a symbolic link which pointed to a file of the same image as the lock-screen background.

Unfortunately changing where the symlink pointed does not seem to change the background image rendered by `gnome-screensaver`.

I tried digging into the source code for `gnome-screensaver` to see how that is set up but I'm not making much headway on it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Gnome-screensaver does not hold config for wallpapers. It is maintained by gnome-shell. You can change wallpaper by command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri file:///path/to/image.jpg
```

If its doesn't change automatically, you can apply change by:

```
gconftool update
```

Comment: So `gsettings` isn't installed on my machine and it doesn't install using apt-get (unable to locate package). Suggestions for how to get it?

Comment: It should be in [libglib2.0-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libglib2.0-bin/filelist) (I found the package name via http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gsettings.1.html). Side note: I modified my Gallium installations to use slock instead.